# pandas: replace values by row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df2
   amount  1  2  3  4
0   5      1  1  1  1
1   7      0  1  1  1
2   9      0  0  0  1
3   8      0  0  1  0
4   2      0  0  0  1
```

What I want to do is replace the 1s on every row with the value of the amount field in that row and leave the zeros as is. The output should look like this

```
   amount  1  2  3  4
0   5      5  5  5  5
1   7      0  7  7  7
2   9      0  0  0  9
3   8      0  0  8  0
4   2      0  0  0  2
```

I've tried applying a lambda function row-wise like this, but I'm running into errors

```
df2.apply(lambda x: x.loc[i].replace(0, x['amount']) for i in len(x), axis=1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: just multiply : 0 returns 0 and 1 returns the amount value: `df.drop('amount',1).mul(df['amount'],axis=0)`

Comment: _but I'm running into errors_ Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Asn aside, why you use 0/1 instead of actual boolean values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use `mask`:

```
df2.mask(df2 == 1, df2['amount'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
   amount  1  2  3  4
0       5  5  5  5  5
1       7  0  7  7  7
2       9  0  0  0  9
3       8  0  0  8  0
4       2  0  0  0  2
```

Comment: For a more general case, maybe use `df2.mask(df2 != 0, df2['amount'], axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it wit [`pandas.DataFrame.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) method, like this:

```
>>> df2.iloc[:, 1:] = df2.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df2['amount'], axis=0)
>>> print(df2)
   amount  1  2  3  4
0       5  5  5  5  5
1       7  0  7  7  7
2       9  0  0  0  9
3       8  0  0  8  0
4       2  0  0  0  2
```